# Find values for $a$, $b$, $c$ that make this linear system solvable?

Tags: linear-algebra

I came along with the following exercise that I developed poorly.  May anybody give me some light?  See:

> How to find a solution involving $a$, $b$, $c$ to make the following system consistent? Find the solutions when possible.
>
> $$x + y + z + t = a$$
> $$5y + 2z + 4t = b$$
> $$3x - 2y + z - t = c$$

Well.  First I tried to reduce the system to the reduced row echelon form, with not very success.  What I got is:

> $$x - \frac{2}{5}t = \frac{5a - b}{5}$$
> $$y + \frac{2}{5}t = \frac{-c + 3a}{5}$$
> $$z + t = \frac{c - 3a + b}{5}$$

I thought it would help, but I don't know how to resume the exercise.

Any tips?

Thank you.

Comment: You had better check you reduction, as what you got is not correct.

Comment: You are right. I fixed the reduction. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first step in row reduction gives the new equation
$$ -5y -2z -4t = c-3a$$
Since the left-hand side of this is minus the left-hand side of the equation for $b$, the equations imply $b=3a-c$.

On the other hand, that same first step of row reduction shows that the rank of the equation system is at least 2, so the column space is at least 2-dimensional. The condition $b=3a-c$ already restricts the possible $(a,b,c)$ to a 2-dimensional subspace, to there is no room for further restrictions.

So the possible $(a,b,c)$ are exactly those that satisfy $b=3a-c$ (or equivalently $3a-b-c=0$ or $b+c=3a$),

Answer (score 1):

*Supposed that this is correct so far*, I think, you can finish it by saying

Let $a,b,c$ be arbitrary, moreover let $t$ be arbitrary too. Then you get unique solution for $x,y,z$ as above.

In other words, for every $a,b,c$ there are infinitely many solutions (as $t$ is arbitrary)..